# How do I change Sourcetree icon shown in Dock?

Tags: macos, dock, icon

I have an app that is very useful, but from time to time it changes its icon in the Dock, which I found disturbing for my workflow.

I would like to prevent that as I am perfectly satisfied with the standard icon.

I've tried following the instructions in the article, [How to change Mac app icons](https://9to5mac.com/2019/01/17/change-mac-icons/) but as soon as the app starts, it changes the icon back.

I've also poked around Contents/Resources directory in the app bundle, but could not find the said icon.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a oneliner solution.

Open terminal and type:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/Pridetree/Bridetree/;' /Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
```

Restart Sourcetree. App icon will be restored to the default one.

Comment: thanks, this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Tnx. Easier than my solution. I'll mark this as answer

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is interested, the issue was Pride icon on SourceTree app. I've found the solution here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-discussions/The-way-to-change-icon-for-Sourcetree-app/td-p/1110914

1. Go to https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine
2. Switch to releases tab (I took the latest pre-release)
3. Download .zip and extract it
4. Open the **Sourcetree.app** with right click - show package contents and navigate to Contents/Resources
5. Copy **Assets.car** and **sourcetree.icns** to any folder
6. Run **ThemeEngine** from the zip in step 3
7. In **ThemeEngine** click "Open Document" and open the **Assets.car**
8. Find the icon named **Pridetree**
9. Open **sourctree.icns** with your preferred app - I used preview. Clicked on second icon pressed cmd + a to select whole image and pressed cmd + c to copy it.
10. Clicked on first image in **Pridetree** **ThemeEngine** and pressed cmd + v to paste it.
11. Repeat with second image.
12. Save the document
13. Replace **Assets.car** in the app Contents/Resources with modified **Assets.car**.

Do not forget to backup your files. Your are doing this on your own risk as I do not know if it actually breaks the EULA.

Comment: Holy F... this icon change has been driving me nuts! I wish companies would stop disrupting my work-flow. Having to temporarily memorize what a new app icon looks like for a week is quite annoying. I keep clicking on the wrong icon!

Comment: Update: Doesn't work on Catalina (10.15).

Comment: @SterlingBourne check my answer…

Answer (score -1):

Without being sure (I'm not in front of my mac now), an .app file is a zip file ... which contains icons. Maybe you can try to change them.

In any case, work on a copy of the .app file, and try to load from that copy (maybe there are some integrity checks).

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596004605/ch01s12.html

Comment: You said, "an .app file is a zip file"... well, **no it's not a zip file**! It's an **application bundle**, which is actually  just and ordinary folder containing other folders and files, but is treated differently because of how the OS handles files with the `.app` extension.

Comment: Indeed, I was confusing. Anyway, zip file or directory, it is possible to change what is inside. Sorry for the confusion.